# sql join has duplicates

Tags: sql, linq, duplicates

My left outer join kept returning exact duplicates until I added distinct to the query.  Why is that?  And how can I convert this query to LINQ:

```
SELECT  distinct
  ADCIC.AccountDairyToCommitmentItemCategoryID, 
  ADCIC.AccountDairyParentID      
from 
  vw_ParentAccountDollarsAllocatedByCommitmentItemCategory vw  
  left outer join tblAccountDairyToCommitmentItemCategory ADCIC  
     ON vw.AccountDairyParentID = ADCIC.AccountDairyParentID        
where  
  vw.FiscalYear = 2015 
  AND vw.AccountDairyParentID = 6478
```

Comment: You might want to ask a new question for converting the query to LINQ, as it's a distinct question

Comment: A left join doesnt return duplicates, but you may not see where the values are unique unless you `select *`.  Distinct will restrict the query to distinct values of those columns that you select.

Comment: As for the linq question, this is an easy one and there are [a LOT of examples of left joins](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=linq%20left%20join%20example) out there.

Comment: I point of clarification about my earlier statement.  If your data is duplicated, then you will get duplicates as well.

Comment: ty paqogomez.  I don't have a good understanding of a left outer join.  If I select all  I do see uniqueness rows.  My view table has 8 rows, only 4 of which have AccountDairyParentID of 6478 so I'm trying to write a query that will only return 4 rows but will include data from the ADCIC table.  That table also only has 8 rows, 4 with AccountDairyParentID of 6478.  I get 16 rows return though if I don't put distinct in the query.  Maybe a left outer join is the wrong approach.  If adding "distinct" into my query is not the right approach, should I be doing a subselect or something else?

Answer (score 0):

this is a wild guess and i know i may get downvotes for this but

check tblAccountDairyToCommitmentItemCategory table has FiscalYear column if yes then i think you need to add FiscalYear in your join condition

you might want to try following query

```
SELECT  
  ADCIC.AccountDairyToCommitmentItemCategoryID, 
  ADCIC.AccountDairyParentID      
from 
  vw_ParentAccountDollarsAllocatedByCommitmentItemCategory vw  
  left outer join tblAccountDairyToCommitmentItemCategory ADCIC  
     ON vw.AccountDairyParentID = ADCIC.AccountDairyParentID
     and vw.FiscalYear = ADCIC.FiscalYear   
where  
  vw.FiscalYear = 2015 
  AND vw.AccountDairyParentID = 6478
```